# XMLHttpRequest Error in passing value on url

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

Here I have two fields: name & password. I have been to trying to echo the value using XMLHttpRequest, but when I click submit, it only shows the name and not the password. Please help me find where I have gone wrong.

------------Index.html--------------

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fist Ajax Application</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    }else{      
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

var uname = document.getElementById('username').value;
var upassword = document.getElementById('userpassword').value;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;    
        }

    }
url = "testform.php?name="+uname+"&password="+upassword;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="username" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password" id="userpassword" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="suubmit" onClick="test()" />
<p><div id="results"> Results...</div></p>



</body>
</html>
```

---

-----------------Testform.php---------------

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$password = $GET['password'];

echo $password."<br />";
echo $name."<br />";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$password = $_GET['password'];` instead of `$password = $GET['password'];`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems,

> First:  You were asking the DOM, to get the element while the page had
>   not completed loading.
>
> Second: is as the previous user pointed out. this **$GET['password'];**
>   is invalid syntax:

Now, change your `Ajax` to:

```
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="username" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password" id="userpassword" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="suubmit" onClick="test()" />
<p><div id="results"> Results...</div></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    }else{      
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

var uname = document.getElementById('username').value;
var upassword = document.getElementById('userpassword').value;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;    
        }

    }

xmlhttp.open("GET","testform.php?name="+uname+"&password="+upassword, true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}

console.log(test())
</script>
```

And, your `PHP` file,

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET)): 
$name = $_GET['name'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

echo $password."<br />";
echo $name."<br />";


endif;

?>
```